# Access Common Block variables from ctypes

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes

I am trying to access the data stored in a Fortran 77 common block from a Python script. The question is that I don't know where this data is stored.
The Python application that I am developing makes use of different libraries. These libraries contain functions with the following directives:

```
#include <tcsisc_common.inc>
```

The common block contains:

```
C
      INTEGER*4 IDEBUG
C
C.... ARRAY DIMENSIONS
      DIMENSION IDEBUG(10)
C
C.... COMMON BLOCK
      COMMON /TCSD/ IDEBUG
C
```

On the Python part (on the example I have used iPython), I load the library:

```
In [1]: import ctypes
In [2]: _libtcsisc= /home/jfreixa/project/bin/libtcsisc.so
In [3]: _tcsisc   = ctypes.CDLL(_libtcsisc, ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get IDEBUG. I have tried the following, but I just get tcsd as a c_long initialized to 0.

```
In [4]: tcsd = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(_tcsisc, "TCSD_")
In [5]: tcsd
Out[5]: c_long(0)
In [6]: idebug = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(_tcsisc, "IDEBUG_")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ee5018286275> in <module>()

----> 1 idebug = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(_tcsisc,'IDEBUG_')

ValueError: ld.so.1: python2.7: fatal: IDEBUG_: can't find symbol
```

Any idea to correctly get the variable?

Comment: Why don't you write fortran functions that python can call to get access to those variable.

Comment: Because the libraries were developed long time ago and I want to avoid try to translate a validated infrastructure. Accessing the variables in the common blocks will allow me to make use of them in Python (the part that needs to be updated) and leave the hundreds of functions on Fortran that does not need to be updated.

Comment: Writing a wrapper does not mean updating anything! You would just write a Fortran setter and getter, completely new procedures. Nothing to change at all! Your hundreds of functions can stay untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html) (particularly how to access Fortran common blocks from C) and some [Q/A page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346835/how-to-access-to-c-global-variable-structure-by-python-and-ctype) about how to access C struct from Python, it seems that we could access common blocks as follows (though this may be not very portable, see below):

mylib.f90

```
subroutine fortsub()
    implicit none
    integer n
    common /mycom/ n
    print *, "fortsub> current /mycom/ n = ", n
end
```

compile:

```
$ gfortran -shared -fPIC -o mylib.so mylib.f90
```

test.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ctypes

class Mycom( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [ ( "n", ctypes.c_int ) ]

mylib = ctypes.CDLL( "./mylib.so" )

mycom = Mycom.in_dll( mylib, "mycom_" )

print( " python> modifying /mycom/ n to 777" )

mycom.n = 777

fortsub = mylib.fortsub_
fortsub()
```

Test:

```
 $ python test.py 
 python> modifying /mycom/ n to 777
 fortsub> current /mycom/ n =          777
```

Here, please note that the name of the common block (here, `mycom`) is made lowercase and one underscore attached (by assuming gfortran). Because this convention is compiler-dependent, it may be more robust/portable to write new Fortran routines for setting/getting values in common blocks (particularly with the help of `iso_c_binding`) and call those routines from Python (as suggested by @innoSPG in the first comment).

---

Another example including different types and arrays may look like this:

mylib.f90

```
subroutine initcom()
    implicit none
    integer          n( 2 ), w  !! assumed to be compatible with c_int
    real             f( 2 )     !!                      ... with c_float
    double precision d( 2 )     !!                      ... with c_double
    common /mycom/ n, f, d, w

    print *, "(fort) initializing /mycom/"
    n(:) = [ 1, 2 ]
    f(:) = [ 3.0, 4.0 ]
    d(:) = [ 5.0d0, 6.0d0 ]
    w    = 7
    call printcom()
end

subroutine printcom()
    implicit none
    integer          n( 2 ), w
    real             f( 2 )
    double precision d( 2 )
    common /mycom/ n, f, d, w

    print *, "(fort) current /mycom/"
    print *, "       n = ", n
    print *, "       f = ", f
    print *, "       d = ", d
    print *, "       w = ", w
end
```

test.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ctypes

N = 2

class Mycom( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [ ( "x", ctypes.c_int    * N ),
                 ( "y", ctypes.c_float  * N ),
                 ( "z", ctypes.c_double * N ),
                 ( "w", ctypes.c_int        ) ]

mylib = ctypes.CDLL( "./mylib.so" )

mycom = Mycom.in_dll( mylib, "mycom_" )

initcom = mylib.initcom_
initcom()

print( " (python) current /mycom/" )
print( "          x = ", mycom.x[:] )
print( "          y = ", mycom.y[:] )
print( "          z = ", mycom.z[:] )
print( "          w = ", mycom.w    )

print( " (python) modifying /mycom/ ..." )
for i in range( N ):
    mycom.x[ i ] = (i + 1) * 10
    mycom.y[ i ] = (i + 1) * 100
    mycom.z[ i ] = (i + 1) * 0.1
mycom.w = 777

printcom = mylib.printcom_
printcom()
```

Test:

```
 $ python test.py

 (fort) initializing /mycom/
 (fort) current /mycom/
        n =            1           2
        f =    3.0000000       4.0000000    
        d =    5.0000000000000000        6.0000000000000000     
        w =            7
 (python) current /mycom/
          x =  [1, 2]
          y =  [3.0, 4.0]
          z =  [5.0, 6.0]
          w =  7
 (python) modifying /mycom/ ...
 (fort) current /mycom/
        n =           10          20
        f =    100.00000       200.00000    
        d =   0.10000000000000001       0.20000000000000001     
        w =          777
```

Comment: When a remark or warning appears about the alignment of common variables, it may be necessary to add some option (e.g., -align for ifort) when compiling the fortran source. This is also compiler-dependent, so to avoid that, it may be more convenient (eventually) to write getter/setter routines for necessary common variables rather than directly accessing them from python.