# Access Fortran Common Variables from Cython

Tags: python, fortran, cython, fortran-iso-c-binding

My question is virtually identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39540375/673590).  However, I'm looking for a solution that uses Cython instead of ctypes.

I'm wrapping some legacy F77 code for using in Python. I've written wrappers for the subroutines, using a module and the iso_c_bindings, that I can then use from Cython. This works well for calling the subroutines, passing data as arguments, etc. However, I'd now like to access the common block data in the library directly from Cython.

So my question is two parts:

A) Can I access the common block data using Cython directly as in the ctypes example above? I so how? I gather I'm supposed to reference the common block as a struct using `cdef extern`, but I'm not sure how to point to the library data.

B) Would I be better off, and not sacrifice performance, by simply writing setter/getter functions in my wrapper module?  This was suggested in the responses to the ctypes question referenced above.

Comment: Rather than wrapping with Cython, it might be easier to wrap this with `f2py`.  There is some example usage on the [scipy f2py usage page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/python-usage.html).

Comment: I've used F2PY for other libraries.  It works well, and yes provides access to common block data. However, in other projects I'm linking to code that uses fortran derived types as well, which F2PY can not handle, but are readily used in Cython. So I've been searching for a Cython solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) After trial & error, it seems that the following code works with python3.5/gfortran4.8/cython0.25 on Linux x86_64, so could you try it to see whether it works or not...?

fort.f90:

```
module mymod
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
contains

subroutine fortsub() bind(c)
    double precision x( 2 )
    real             y( 3 )
    real             z( 4 )
    integer          n( 5 )
    common /mycom/ x, y, z, n

    data z / 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0 /  !! initialize only z(:) (for check)

    print *, "(fort) x(:) = ", x(:)
    print *, "(fort) y(:) = ", y(:)
    print *, "(fort) z(:) = ", z(:)
    print *, "(fort) n(:) = ", n(:)
end subroutine

end module
```

fort.h:

```
extern void fortsub( void );   /* or fortsub_() if bind(c) is not used */

extern struct Mycom {
    double x[ 2 ];
    float  y[ 3 ];
    float  z[ 4 ];
    int    n[ 5 ];
} mycom_;
```

test.pyx:

```
cdef extern from "fort.h":
    void fortsub()

    struct Mycom:
        double x[ 2 ]
        float  y[ 3 ]
        int    n[ 5 ]

    Mycom mycom_;

def go():

    mycom_.x[:] = [ 1.0, 2.0 ]
    mycom_.y[:] = [ 11.0, 12.0, 13.0 ]
    mycom_.n[:] = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

    fortsub()
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from os import system

system( 'gfortran -c fort.f90 -o fort.o -fPIC' )

ext_modules = [Extension( 'test', ['test.pyx'],
                          extra_compile_args = ['-fPIC'],
                          extra_link_args = ['fort.o', '-lgfortran'] )]

setup( name = 'test',
       cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
       ext_modules = ext_modules )
```

compile:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

test:

```
$ python
>>> import test
>>> test.go()
 (fort) x(:) =    1.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000     
 (fort) y(:) =    11.0000000       12.0000000       13.0000000    
 (fort) z(:) =    100.000000       200.000000       300.000000       400.000000    
 (fort) n(:) =            1           2           3           4           5
```

Here, please note that I did not include `z` in `test.pyx` to check whether we can declare only selected variables in the common block. Also, some compiler options may be necessary to make the alignment of common variables consistent between C and Fortran ([this YoLinux page](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html) may be useful).

---

B) I guess it would depend on the amount of computation peformed by the Fortran routine... If the routine is heavy (takes at least a few minutes), copy operations in getter/setter may be no problem. On the other hand, if the routine finishes quickly while called a huge number of times, then the overhead may be non-negligible...

For efficiency, it might be useful to pass pointer variables from Cython to Fortran, get the address of selected `common` variables somehow by `c_loc()`, and access them via pointers on the Cython side directly (though not still sure if it works...) But if there is no problem of memory alignment (for the compiler used), it may be more straight-forward to use structs as above.

Comment: Excellent answer!  I didn't implement your answer directly, but using your example I was able to setup my external references in Cython correctly.  Where I was stuck was in how to reference the common block "struct". This was the missing piece, `Mycom mycom_`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already familiar with modular programming, I suggest you put the `common` block in a module and import the variables when access is required:

```
module common_block_mod
    common /myCommonBlock/ var, var2, var3
    save ! This is not necessary in Fortran 2008+
end module common_block_mod
```

You can now import the variables when access is required.

```
subroutine foo()
    use common_block_mod
    !.. do stuff
end subroutine foo
```

You can read more about this approach at http://iprc.soest.hawaii.edu/users/furue/improve-fortran.html

Comment: This doesn't really tell the user how to access/modify the values in Cython unless you're suggesting that OP write getters/setters for every value in the common block...

Comment: I was under the impression that the OP already has routines to access module variables and procedures(functions/subroutines).

Comment: Thanks @jlokimlin, this is precisely what I have done. I didn't mention it since it didn't seem relevant. What I need is a mechanism for accessing the common block variables using Cython. I think there is something about accessing external data from Cython that I don't understand.